# Show for $\ c>0\ $ that $\ cY\sim \ \text{Gamma}(\alpha,c\beta)$

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions, gamma-distribution

> Show for any constant $\ c>0\ $ that $\ cY\sim \ \text{Gamma}(\alpha,c\beta)$
>   $$Y\sim\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$$ 
>   $$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\Gamma (\alpha)\beta^\alpha}e^{\frac{-y}{\beta}}y^{\alpha-1} \ \ \ \ \ y>0$$

Attempt:
I had an intuition that computing the moment generating function of $Y$ may help.
Hence I calculated that 
$$m_Y(u)=(1-\beta u)^{-\alpha} \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{for} \ \ u<\frac{1}{\beta}$$

Now I am unsure of how to proceed. Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why not write $\Gamma(\alpha,c\beta)$?

Comment: @gebruiker: It's more common to write $Gamma(\alpha ,c\beta )$ than $\Gamma(\alpha ,c\beta )$. The notation $\Gamma(a,b)$ is more used for the Incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Did not know that. Thank you

Comment: Why not compute moment generating function of $cY $?

Comment: @AnyAD: Wouldn't this just be $c \ m_Y(u)$ (as $c$ is constant)?

Comment: There are three possible methods to work such 'transformation' problems, sometimes called PDF, CDF, and MGF. Multiplication by a constant is about the simplest case for any one of the three. You have mentioned MGF, @Surb has mentioned the other two. All are worth knowing. For now, study _one_ of them and show the desired result. (Then, sooner or later, study the other 2.) // Whenever you mention a gamma dist'n, you should say whether the 2nd parameter is a _scale_ or _rate_ parameter. Both parameterizations are common. Perhaps see Wilipedia on 'gamma distribution' if your text is unclear.

Comment: MGF: You have written MGF $m_Y(u) = E(e^{uY}) = (1-\beta u)^{-\alpha},$ where $Y$ has PDF $F_Y(y)$ as stated of $\mathsf{Gamma}(shape=\alpha, scale=\beta).$ What must be the MGF of $\mathsf{Gamma}(shape=\alpha, scale=\beta^\prime=c\beta)?$ // Then the MGF of $cY$ is $E(e^{u[cY]}).$ Evaluate that and you're done. // Really helps to read definitions and examples before starting problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

**Method 1 :**
Using the fact that $$\mathbb P\{Y\leq y\}=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha -1}e^{-\frac{x}{\beta }}}{\Gamma(k)\beta ^k}dx,$$
I think that $$\mathbb P\{cY\leq y\}$$
can be easily deduce.

**Method 2 :** If $g$ is a bijection, and if $Y=g(X)$, then
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{f_X(g^{-1}(y))}{|g'(g^{-1}(y)|}$$

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't $$f_Y(y)=\mathbb P\{Y= y\}=\frac{y^{\alpha -1}e^{-\frac{y}{\beta }}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta ^\alpha}?$$ Where did $P\{Y\leq y\}$ come from?

Comment: @Bell The density evaluated ar $y$ does not equal probability at a point which is always zero for a continuous distribution.

Comment: And if I find $\mathbb{P}(cY\leq y)$, how does this help? Sorry, but I'm still a bit unsure.

Comment: @Bell $P(Y\le y)$ is the distribution function of $Y$ which is to be differentiated to get the pdf $f_Y$ of $Y$.